# Why am I not getting a NoSuchElements exception?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I know we usually don't want errors but I am learning web scraping, and I am wondering why my code does not result in a NoSuchElements Exception being printed.

The website I am scraping has 3 states I encounter:

1. Has company names listed, each with a div class called "result-id-#" (the number is unique to each result on the page, so I use regex to find it as follows "companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})" as seen in the code below.
2. HTTP Error when the website is mispelled.
3. A sort of "end of the line" page, that says "sorry no results"/the url can go to page 1000+.  This page has no 'result-id' tag and therefore should give me a NoSuchElements error, however the problem I am having is that I do not get this error, python seems to just go to the next loop.

In the code below, I have purposely started generating the url at page 1000 and gone up to page 1050 in increments of 1.

```
import numpy as np
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#store pages perameter within the pages variable for our loop to iterate through
pageNumbers = np.arange(1000, 1050, 1)

                for page in pageNumbers:
                    url = 'https://www/website.com/page'

                    try:
                        #Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL
                        results = requests.get(str((url) + str(page) + '.html'), headers=headers)
                        
                        #parse html content
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

                        #Grab the container that holds the company info
                        companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})

                        #check for error status
                        results.raise_for_status()

                    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                        print('HTTP Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                        pass
                    
                    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                        print('Timeout Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                        pass

                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        print('No Such Element Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                        pass
                        
                    print('now processing page ' + str(results.url))
```

When I go to page 1, I successfully get the results and it goes to the next page, when I get the timeout error, it simply goes to the next page in the loop, when I purposely misspell the url and get the HTTP error, it also then loops to the next page.

But when I am on the "sorry no results" page, there is no error, and it just iterates up until 1050, even though there is no "result-id" on the page at all (I even changed it from 'results-id-' to 'mickeymouse' and it still just looped to the next page without even acknowledging there was no such result).

Surely it should be saying "Cant find "result-id" should it not?  But instead, when I interrupt the process and print "companies_div", I get an empty list... Sorry this got long but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't look right. You're trying to catch a `selenium` error, but your code is utilizing `bs4`...

Comment: Yeah it looks like requests doesn't have that, and any google search for such a thing only brings up selenium, but I thought it could be imported?

Comment: I think it is because `soup.find_all` will not raise an error when there's no result, it will only give you an empty list. So an extra check on whether the list is empty or not is needed. (and I think it has nothing to do with selenium)

Comment: Thanks @Cheukting, that might be my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a while loop, effectively creating my own NoSuchElementException:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while errorCounter == 0:
   
                    pageNumbers = pageNumbers = itertools.count(1)
                    for page in pageNumbers:
                        url = (baseURL.format(provinceKey, cityKey, catname, code, catcode))

                        try:
                            #Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL
                            results = requests.get(str((url) + str(page) + '.html'), headers=headers)

                             #check for error status
                            results.raise_for_status()

                        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                            print('HTTP Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                            errors.append(str('HTTP Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url)))
                            pass
                        
                        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                            print('Timeout Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                            errors.append(str('Timeout Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url)))
                            pass
                            
                        print('now processing page ' + str(results.url))

                        #parse html content
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

                        #Grab the container that holds the company info
                        companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})
                        if len(companies_div) == 0:
                              print('No Such Element Error encountered while parsing ' + str(results.url))
                              errorCounter = 1
                              print(errorCounter)
                              break

                     errorCounter = 0
                     print(errorCounter)
                     break
```